# Logic to determine whether two number sequences are order equivalent

Tags: comparison, sequence

I want to determine if two sequences are "order equivalent", where what I mean by that is two sequences **a** and **b** are order equivalent if they have the same number of elements and they both contain less than two numbers or if for all i, j, 1 <= i, j <= n where n is the length of a sequence a[i] <= a[j] if and only if b[i] <= b[j]

I have written a small program in C along with a set of test cases

```
include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Should be true, and is
//    int a[1] = {12};
//    int b[1] = {8};

    // Should be true, and is
//    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
//    int b[3] = {12, 32, 43};

    // Should be true, and is
//    int a[3] = {12, 45, 78};
//    int b[3] = {1, 2, 3};

    // Should be true, and is
//    int a[6] = {7, 5, 9, 13, 12};
//    int b[6] = {4, 2, 25, 33, 26};

    // Should be true, and is
//    int a[3] = {1, 1, 1};
//    int b[3] = {1, 1, 1};

    // Should be false, and is
//    int a[4] = {12, 1, 2, 3}; // because there is a decrease between 12 and 1
//    int b[4] = {3, 4, 5, 6}; // but an increase between 3 and 4

    // Should be true, but for some reason is not
    int a[6] = {23, 55, 22, 33, 9, 18};
    int b[6] = {21, 43, 11, 22, 7, 11};

    int size_of_arrays = 6; // set this to the correct value depending on values being tested

    int are_equivalent = 1;
    for (int m = 0; m < size_of_arrays; m = m + 1){
        for (int n = 0; n < size_of_arrays; n = n + 1){
            if ((a[m] <= a[n]) != (b[m] <= b[n])){
                are_equivalent = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (are_equivalent == 1) {
        printf("The two sequences are order equivalent.");
    } else {
        printf("The two sequences are not order equivalent.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but the last test case in particular is throwing me for a loop (pun intended). There is some case my logic is not covering but I am unable to see it. Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: Your final test case, which you've annotated as "should be true", is in fact not true.  Array b has `b[2] == b[5]` (both with value `11`) but array a has `a[2] > a[5]` (with values `22` and `18' respectively).

Comment: You are right! I was mistaken in how I was interpreting the constraints.